# Missing Closing Tag on Dynammically Generated React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a react component with a render function that should return a list of posts that will be styled with `element-ui`'s layout scheme.  The element returned should end up looking something like this:

```
render(){
   return <Layout.Row gutter="20">
          <Layout.Col span="6"><Post id=1/></Layout.Col>
          <Layout.Col span="6"><Post id=2/></Layout.Col>
          <Layout.Col span="6"><Post id=3/></Layout.Col>
          <Layout.Col span="6"><Post id=4/></Layout.Col>
        </Layout.Row>
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this by mapping the posts listed in state to columns.

Edit: updated class to remove typo and updated error message

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
        };
    }
    render(){
        let posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index)=>{
            var el = <Layout.Col span="6">{post.id}</Layout.Col>;
            var result
            if(index%4===0){
                result=<Layout.Row>{el}

            }
            if((index+1)%4===0){
                result={el}</Layout.Row>
            }
            return result
        });
        return (
                <div>{posts}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
 Line 20:  Parsing error: Unterminated regular expression

  18 |      }
  19 |      if((index+1)%4===0){
> 20 |          result={el}</Layout.Row>
     |                       ^
  21 |      }
  22 |      return result
  23 |  });
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to achieve this format using React?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the column components in rows :

```
let posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index)=>{
            var el = <Layout.Col span="6">{post.id}</Layout.Col>; //here col to Col
            if(index%4===0){
                return <Layout.Row>{el}</Layout.Row> //here

            }
            if((index+1)%4===0){
                return <Layout.Row>{el}</Layout.Row> //and here
            }

        });
```

EDIT:

Following comment, easiest way to both simplify your code and fix your error might be:

```
let posts = <Layout.Row>
  {
    this.state.posts.map((post)=> (
      <Layout.Col span="6">{post.id}</Layout.Col>
    ))
  }
  </Layout.Row>;
```

Comment: If I do it that way, the rows will consist of only one column, but they should consist of 4

Comment: So I guess you need to do :
`let posts = <Layout.Row>{this.state.posts.map((post, index)=> <Layout.Col span="6">{post.id}</Layout.Col>)}</Layout.Row>;
`

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo:

```
 <Layout.Col span="6">{post.id}</Layout.col>;
```

should be

```
 <Layout.Col span="6">{post.id}</Layout.Col>;
```

Comment: thanks for spotting that, corrected it in my question.  The issue is still there, though.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is that you wrote `</Layout.col>` instead of `</Layout.Col>`.

EDIT:

Based on your comments, the code should look something like this:

```
render() {
  const { posts } = this.state;
  const cols = posts.map(post => <Layout.Col span="6">{post.id}</Layout.Col>);
  const columnsPerRow = 4;
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i += columnsPerRow) {
    let cols = cols.slice(i, i + columnsPerRow);
    rows.push(<Layout.Row>{cols}</Layout.Row>);
  }
  return <div>{rows}</div>;
}
```

Comment: that was one problem, but I corrected it and the issue is still there

Comment: I see a problem in you code. Your render function is syntactically and logically wrong. What do you want to achieve by counting to 4 and using the modulo in if-expression?

Comment: I want the result to match the layout I wrote in the top of my question.  The modulo expression is meant to create `Layout.Row` elements with 4 `Layout.Col` elements between them.

Comment: I think that you don't need a modulo, check my edited answer.